# std::deque : What does "insertion and deletion of elements may invalidate iterators" mean?

Tags: c++, deque

I was reading about the std::deque container and the document states that

> Insertion and deletion of elements in std::deque may invalidate all
>   its iterators

Here is my version of understanding of the above statement kindly let me know if I am misinterpreting the statement or missing something

Consider the following code

```
std::deque<int> s;
s.push_back(12);
auto i = s.begin();
s.push_front(45);//After pushing 45 at the back now `i` may be invalid.
```

Is this understanding correct ?

Comment: Yes, this understanding is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. For example after

```
std::deque<int> s;
s.push_back(12);
auto i = s.begin();
s.push_front(45)
```

calling `*i` is undefined behavior.